# Missing add to cart button on my custom product type in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a custom plugin that is adding a custom product type "Metal" to products. Everything seems alright, the plugin is almost finished but the problem is that the "Add to cart" button does not appear anywhere on the front website. I tried so many solutions googling my problem but the only thing I could do is to display the add to cart functionality on the product page but not on the shop page. I achieved that adding an action

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_metal_add_to_cart', fn() => wc_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php' ));
```

using the simple product template. Now, the problem is that the button does not appear on the shop page. How can I display the "Add to cart" button on the shop page? I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function wc_get_template to include the "Add to cart" template for your custom product type in the overridden shop page template. It could look something like this:

```
if( $product->is_type( 'metal' ) ) {
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php' );
} else {
    wc_get_template( 'loop/add-to-cart.php' );
}
```

Comment: Please, note that Im a beginner. Do I need to use this code in a specific hook or? I tried using your code in the function's hook I provided in the question but I'm getting an error "Call to a member function is_type() on string"